# Any idea how to put Python cmd.Cmd interaction into GUI?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a game were the main player of the game will be controlled by Python script, entered interactively. Or, in other word, it will be controlled within a Python REPL environment.

Having seen Python [cmd.Cmd](http://pymotw.com/2/cmd/) pakcage in action, I am sure that it will be a great candidate for the REPL environment I wish to build. Hence, my next step is putting cmd.Cmd interaction into a GUI input, in which it will be the same as Python IDLE in Windows seen below:
[image: Python IDLE Window]

Any idea how to put cmd.Cmd interaction into a GUI text editor?

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at IDLE's source code and see how it does it.

Comment: Yeah, actually I just get that idea after taking this screenshot. Although, I nice code sample of how to integrate cmd.Cmd will be superb!